# Calculating distance in m in xyz between GPS coordinates that are close together

Tags: gps, distance

I have a set of GPS Coordinates and I want to find the speed required for a UAV to travel between them. Doing this by calculating distance in x y z and then dividing by time to travel - m/s.

I know the great circle distance but I assume this will be incorrect since they are all relatively close together(within 10m)?

Is there an accurate way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

For small distances you can use the [haversine formula](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) without a relevant loss of accuracy in comparison to Vincenty's f.e. Plus, it's designed to be accurate for very small distances. This can be read up [here](http://daimi.au.dk/~dam/thesis/Sky_and_Telescope_1984.pdf) if you are interested.

Comment: Hi, yes I used that but the issue is I need x and y components. Haversine gives the resultant distance.

Comment: You need the position, which is an amount of meters away from a starting point or the distance as a vector representation?

Comment: The amount in metres in the x and y direction, so I can then calculate speeds. I have just thought about converting to ECEF and then subtracting the difference?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by converting lat/long/alt into XYZ format for both points.  Then, figure out the rotation angles to move one of those points (usually, the oldest point) so that it would be at lat=0 long=0 alt=0.   Rotate the second position report (the newest point) by the same rotation angles.  If you do it all correctly, you will find X equals the east offset, Y equals the north offset, and Z equals the up offset.  You can use Pythagorean theorm with X and Y (north and east) offsets to determine the horizontal distance traveled.  Normally, you just ignore the altitude differences and work with horizontal data only.

All of this assumes you are using accurate formulas to convert lat/lon/alt into XYZ.  It also assumes you have enough precision in the lat/lon/alt values to be accurate.  Approximations are not good if you want good results.  Normally, you need about 6 decimal digits of precision in lat/lon values to compute positions down to the meter level of accuracy.

Keep in mind that this method doesn't work very well if you haven't moved far (greater than about 10 or 20 meters, more is better).  There is enough noise in the GPS position reports that you are going to get jumpy velocity values that you will need to further filter to get good accuracy.  The math approach isn't the problem here, it's the inherent noise in the GPS position reports.  When you have good reports, you will get good velocity.

A GPS receiver doesn't normally use this approach to know velocity.  It looks at the way doppler values change for each satellite and factor in current position to know what the velocity is.  This works reasonably well when the vehicle is moving.  It is a much faster way to detect changes in velocity (for instance, to release a position clamp).  The normal user doesn't have access to the internal doppler values and the math gets very complicated, so it's not something you can do.

Comment: A few more things.  When I say "convert to XYZ", what I really mean is "convert to XYZ coordinates in the ECEF coordinate system."

Comment: When I say "rotate the points to lat=0 lon=0 alt=0", what I really mean is "X=6378137 Y=0 Z=0".  These XYZ coordinates correspond to lat=0 lon=0 alt=0 when using the WGS-84 Datum.

Comment: You also have to make sure your lat/lon/alt are referenced to the correct datum.  GPS receivers will use the WGS-84 datum internally to compute all lat/lon/alt values, but you may find that another software layer converts this to a different datum like NAD-27.  Your calculations will be off if you don't use the right datum.

Comment: Finally, XYZ values in the ECEF coordinate system are expressed in meters, like any good coordinate system should.  Everything is metric, not miles or feet.